# GLMM for binomially distributed outcome, testing differential hypothesis

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, post-hoc, lme4-nlme

I am trying to find a way, to investigate differences between conditions in an experiment. The design is as follows:

**Depended Variable:** Logical (answer is correct [correct accepted or correct rejected] or false [falsely accepted or falsely rejected), with a 50% guessing rate.

**Independent Variable:** 1 Factor (11 different conditions, every trial is selected randomly from one of the conditions)

**Subjects:** balanced within-subject design, means every subject performs 60 trials in every condition of the IV

As far as I understand, I can include subject as random effect, since I assume, that there are differences in performance between the subjects (which I am not interested in).

I am working with R, and this is what my model looks like:

```
Outcome ~ Condition + (1|Subject)         ,family = binomial
```

This model gives me i-1 ( = 10) estimated coefficients plus the intercept (one parameter for every condition) and a correlation matrix for the fixed effects.

Here are my concerns:
Does this model even fit? Since a Trial can only be from one condition, only one of the 10 estimated coefficients may apply to the prediction for the outcome of that trial. As far, as I understand, this is where the dummy-coding gets involved, meaning that my intercept is the “percentage correct” (because the mean of a logical vector is the proportion of “trues” in percent) and every other estimated coefficient is the deviation of the mean from that condition to the first condition (coded as intercept). Since the values from to model are obviously not percentages, hence not probabilities, I guess that they are logits, because GLM is a linear model (I know, it might be obvious for some, but not for me..).

So far, so confusing. There are two big Questions I can’t figure out:

1. Assuming, that my model is correct, how would I conduct post-hoc tests (with, let’s say, Tukey Contrasts)?
2. R outputs p-values (“Pr(>|z|)”) for the estimated coefficients in the GLMM. What do they stand for? I guess they show me, whether this estimated coefficient adds significant prediction value to the model, so when they are non-significant, the model would estimate the outcome as good as without them (within random variation accounted for).

I would like to hear your comments and suggestions on that topic and also, if you can recommend any literature, please do so! I had a hard time, finding much information on this topic, which is also understandable for me, since I haven’t study math. I think that is the case, because these kind of models are not quite as popular as the ANOVA / LM model. But I also didn’t want to follow my colleges, who transform their data into a “percentage correct” value for each participant in every condition and then conduct an ANOVA (completely ignoring the amount of trials that participants went through, during the experiment)

I look forward to your comments, and want to thank you in advance for your brain work, put into my question.

**Edit:**

For post-hoc tests I found out, that I can use:

```
lsmeans(model)
```

or:

```
summary(glht(model))
```

since I have a balanced design, it doesn't make a difference, wich test I use. Is this the correct procedure?